# Tracing email on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I have a website that I run together with a contact form on it. It runs on a Server with Microsoft Server 2003 installed on it. Now everything seems to work 100% when submitting the form, no error messages come up. This used to work in the past but not anymore, did not make any changes. Is it possible to check on the server if the mails have been rejected or trace the path that the mail went?

Comment: Where is the mail server? What is the mail server?

Comment: The server is being used to send mails as well

Comment: Ok, but what mail server are you using, IIS SMTP server, or other server.

Comment: Normal smtp from IIS

Answer (score 4):

If the machine is running the Microsoft IIS SMTP server, you can turn up logging (assuming it's not already turned on) and review the logs it generates.

- [Configuring the SMTP Service](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/3e27a577-a6e3-4b0b-9379-68efb5d52ee9.mspx?mfr=true)

The logs for the default SMTP server instance will be located in the %SystemRoot%\System32\Logfiles\SMTPSVC1 directory (typically "C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LogFiles\SMTPSVC1).

If you're using some other email server application then, obviously, it will have its own logging mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

best way to figure out whats going on is to turn logging on for SMTP.  This is not on by default.  It's your best chance of finding out why mail isnt getting to its destination.

Take a look in `C:\inetpub\mailroot\badmail`. If there are files in there with a .eml extension, these are your lost messages! You can open them up with outlook express & have a look at what's in them. There should also be a .BDR file with the same name as the .eml that you can open in notepad & will tell you why your mail has been bad & not sent.

If your folder is empty, then your email has been accepted for delivery and there may be other reasons for it not being delivered, such as spam filtering.